# Rotate Vector to Connect Points

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation, rotations

Give the $[x,y,z]$ cords for two points and a line-segment. The length of the line-segment is equal to the distance between the points, and the midpoint of the segment is at the midpoint of the line between the two points. The line-segment is along the $y$-axis, i.e magnitude $[0, 1, 0]$

How would you calculate the axis about an angle by which to rotate the line-segment such that after the rotation its ends are touching the two points?

Comment: Just define a circle which center $C$ is the mid point of the line segment $L$ and radius $R$ is a vector from $C$ to one of the line ends. Then the axis of rotation is a line passing through the center with direction vector $n = (L \times R)/\| L \times R \|$ parallel to normal vector to the circle, the angle of rotation is $\theta = \cos^{-1}((L \cdot R)/\|L\|\|R\|)$.

Answer (score 0):

We are given:
$\vec{P1}$, $\vec{P2}$, and $\vec{segment}$. Also that the midpoint of $\vec{segment}$ and midpoint of the line connecting $\vec{P1}$, $\vec{P2}$ are the same point.

Here is how I solved it:
$$\vec{connect} = \vec{P1} - \vec{P2}$$

We'll want to rotate $\vec{segment}$ in the plane span by $\vec{segment}$ and $\vec{connect}$ ie the only plane that they are both in (coplanar). This is how we will get $\vec{segment}$ and $\vec{connect}$ to be colinear, our goal. Another way to say this is we will want to rotate $\vec{segment}$ about a vector normal to this plane, or to both $\vec{segment}$ and $\vec{connect}$. Such a vector is found using the cross product.

From the definition of cross product:
$$\vec{axisOfRotation} = \vec{connect}\times\vec{segment}= |\vec{connect}||\vec{segment}|\sin{\theta} \hat{n}$$
so
$$|\vec{axisOfRotation}| = |\vec{connect}\times\vec{segment}|= |\vec{connect}||\vec{segment}|\sin{\theta}$$

thus
$$\theta = \arcsin{\frac{|\vec{axisOfRotation}|}{|\vec{connect}||\vec{segment}|}}$$

I used the `math.js` library to find $\vec{axisOfRotation}$ but the calculations isn't hard to do. I was able to perform a rotation about $\vec{axisOfRotation}$ by the amount $\theta$.